# jQuery - How do I count children and apply percentage based width

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use jQuery to count the number of child elements (in this case list elements) inside div id #foo and then divide 100 / (# of counted child elements).  The last step would be to apply that as a percentage based width

```
<style="width: Npx">
```

Where N = [100/(# of child elements)]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(it takes care of case when there are not children in foo):

```
var el = $('#foo');
var len = el.children().length;
if(len > 0){
    len = 100/len;
    el.css("width",  len + "px"); 
}
```

Comment: Like this one best because it accounts for a fixed width container which is usually better than % based.  +1 for improving my concept!

Comment: Downvote...This should not say "px". It should say "%". If you leave it like this and you have 4 elements it will make them 25px NOT 25%. OP stated in the title percentage NOT pixels.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('someelement').width((100 / $('#foo').find('li').length));
```

You should do a check if the `.length` is zero, to avoid a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = $('#foo > *').length;
$('#bar').css({width:(100/count)+'%'});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="foo">
        <ul>
            <li>Baseball</li>
            <li>Basketball</li>
            <li>Football</li>
            <li>Soccer</li>
            <li>Hockey</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var sWidth = "auto";
            var liLength = $("#foo li").length;
            alert(liLength);
            if (liLength > 0) {
                sWidth = (100 / liLength) + "%";
            }
            $("#foo").width(sWidth);
            alert(sWidth);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```